# Expanded row in angular don't stay align with header

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, primeng-table

I'm trying to get the rowexpansion to be aligned with the header, but for some reason this isn't happening.

My idea is that when I click on expand, the values are aligned with the menu, but I'm not able to make it stay. Is there a problem with my html structure?

```
<div class="ui-g-12">
        <p-table [columns]="6" [value]="list" dataKey="Id" [lazy]="true" styleClass="myClass">
            <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
                <tr>
                    <th id="Menu1" style="width: 4em !important"></th>
                    <th id="Menu2">{{ 'Menu2'  }}</th>
                    <th id="Menu3">{{ 'Menu3'  }}</th>
                    <th id="Menu4">{{ 'Menu4'  }}</th>
                    <th id="Menu5" style="width: 15% !important">
                        {{ 'Menu5' }}
                    </th>
                    <th id="Menu6">{{ 'Menu6' }}</th>
                    <th id="Menu7">{{ 'Menu7' }}</th>
                    <th id="Menu8" *ngIf="" style="width: 10% !important">{{ 'Menu8' }}</th>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
            
            <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-expanded="expanded" let-columns="columns">
                
                // MY BODY WORKS FINE
                
            </ng-template>
            
            <ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
                <tr *">
                    <td [attr.colspan]="6" style="background-color: blue !important">
                        <table aria-describedby="table">
                            <th id="empty - only for sonar"></th>
                            <tbody style="background-color: yellow; z-index: 50">
                                <div *ngFor="">
                                    <div *ngIf="">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ value }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ value }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ value }}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <span
                                                    style="display: grid">
                                                    {{ value }}
                                                    
                                                </span>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                {{ value }}
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ng-template>
        </p-table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Set vertical-align (css) to top. Target your td elements. From your pic appears to be at the default of middle. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align